# Is there a way I can run c++ functions inside Java without using SWIG?

Tags: java, c++, wrapper

I want to create a wrapper for c++ so I can run code that I wrote in Java. Is there a way to achieve this without using SWIG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, JNI is the only way to run foreign language code inside Java app. Other solutions like SWIG are just JNI wrappers.

If you have only 1-2 functions to call from Java code, SWIG may be an overkill. Try reading SWIG documentation: https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_overview

Summarizing you can use raw JNI or try JNI wrappers like SWIG